# Why are extenders defined using finite sequences?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

My question is inspired by definitions 3.1 and 3.2 (3) of ["Double helix in large large cardinals and iteration of elementary embeddings" by Kentaro Sato 2007](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.apal.2007.02.003) but I think my question is relevant to what most set theorists call extenders, despite Sato's unusual terminology. The relevant part of definition 3.1 is:

> For ordinals $\mu \le \lambda$, partition space(s) [...] $\mathcal{E}_{\lambda,\mu}$ [is] defined as follows:
> $$\mathit{P} \in \mathcal{E}_{\lambda,\mu} \iff (\exists \mathit{a} \subset \lambda)(\vert\mathit{a}\vert \lt \omega \And \mathit{P} \sqsupset \{\{\mathit{s} \in D(\mathcal{E}_{\lambda,\mu} \mid \mathit{s}\upharpoonright\mathit{a} = \mathit{f} \} \mid \mathit{f} \in ^\mathit{a}\mu \})$$

**Why are the sets $\mathit{a}$** (which determine whether functions $\mathit{s}$ belong to a given $\mathit{E}$-large set for some ultrafilter $\mathit{E}$) **restricted to be finite?** With higher bounds on the size of $\mathit{a}$ I can probably prove closure properties of ultrapowers by ultrafilters of $\mathcal{E}_{\lambda,\mu}$ (extenders), which would be useful for placing [ultrahuge cardinals](http://cantorsattic.info/Huge#Ultrahuge_cardinals) in the large cardinal hierarchy, but with the bound $\omega$ it's not obvious to me that the ultrapower is even countably closed.

Comment: When an extender $E$ is derived from an embedding $j:M\to N$, the indices $a$ are elements of $N$ (and $E_a$ is the measure derived from $j$ with seed $a$). If you want, you can define an extender with whatever elements of $N$ as indices, including $\omega$-sequences of $N$ that are in $N$. But often $N$ will not be closed under $\omega$-sequences, so it's then not typical to expect that the indices be closed under $\omega$-sequences. Assuming $M,N$ model ZFC, their sets are coded by sets of ordinals in them, which makes it sufficient to use finite sets of ordinals as indices.