# Why are strong cardinals tall?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

[Cantor's Attic](http://web.archive.org/web/20191005075141/http://cantorsattic.info/Tall) defined tall cardinals as follows:

> A cardinal $\kappa$ is $\theta$-tall iff there is an elementary embedding $j:V \to M$ into a transitive class $M$ with critical point $\kappa$ such that $j(\kappa) \gt \theta$ and $M^\kappa \subset M$. $\kappa$ is tall iff it is $\theta$-tall for every $\theta$; i.e. $j(\kappa)$ can be made arbitrarily large.

It also claimed that every strong cardinal is tall. Why is that? It doesn't follow immediately from the definition of strong cardinals, and as far as I know, [extenders can't even ensure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4236848/why-are-extenders-defined-using-finite-sequences) that $M^\omega \subset M$

Most of what I know about extenders comes from the paper [Double helix in large large cardinals and iteration of elementary embeddings](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.apal.2007.02.003) by Kentaro Sato, whose definition 3.2(3) (which relies on definition 3.1) seems to be roughly the same as what other set theories call extenders.

Comment: Who is $V$ here?

Comment: @Vincent I think $V$ is the Von Neumann universe.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\kappa$ be strong and let $\gamma$ be a strong limit cardinal of cofinality $>\kappa$. Let $E$ be a short extender of strength $\gamma$ and support $\gamma$ and critical point $\kappa$. Using that $V_\gamma$ is closed under $\kappa$-sequences, show that $M=\mathrm{Ult}(V,E)$ is also.

Comment: But I have no idea how to prove that. [This paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.apal.2007.02.003) proves an analogous result as part of lemma 3.6, but for extenders the restriction that indices have to be finite, so that a union of infinitely many indices is not generally an index, ruins that proof idea.

Comment: Also, the result you're claiming would also answer [another question that I've asked before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4524805/closure-of-extender-ultrapowers-2?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Let $\vec{x}=\left<x_\alpha\right>_{\alpha<\kappa}\subseteq M=\mathrm{Ult}(V,E)$. Let $\left<f_\alpha,b_\alpha\right>_{\alpha<\kappa}$ be s.t. $b_\alpha\in[\gamma]^{<\omega}$ and $x_\alpha=[b_\alpha,f_\alpha]^V_E$, and so $x_\alpha=j(f_\alpha)(b_\alpha)$ where $j:V\to M$ is the ultrapower map. Let $\vec{f}=\left<f_\alpha\right>_{\alpha<\kappa}$. Note $\vec{g}=j(\vec{f})\upharpoonright\kappa=\left<j(f_\alpha)\right>_{\alpha<\kappa}\in M$. But also $\vec{b}=\left<b_\alpha\right>_{\alpha<\kappa}\in V_\gamma\subseteq M$. From $\vec{g},\vec{b}$, we get $\vec{x}$, as $x_\alpha=g_\alpha(b_\alpha)$.

Comment: What do you mean by $[b_\alpha, f_\alpha]^V_E$ and why does it follow that $x_\alpha=j(f_\alpha)(b_\alpha)$?

Comment: That is the object represented by the pair $(b_\alpha,f_\alpha)$ in the ultrapower of $V$ by $E$. Here we may assume that $f_\alpha:[\kappa]^{|b_\alpha|}\to V$.

Comment: Now I get that part (the ultrafilters described in the paper linked above are not quite extenders and the difference confused me). However, I still don't understand how to prove that $[b_\alpha,f_\alpha]_E^V=j(f_\alpha)(b_\alpha)$